# Capitalizing first letter of each word malfunction when word contains special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this line to capitalize all the first alphabets of each word

```
text.replace(/\b\w^\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase());
```

it successfully capitalize normal words e.g `asif saeed` -> `Asif Saeed`

but when capitalizing name like `"anna alàs i jové"` it converts this to `"Anna AlàS I Jové"` `S` should not be capital after `à`. Plus can we have a solution in which it ignore the word with single alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
var text = "anna alàs i jové";
String.prototype.initCap = function() {
  return this.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)[a-z]/g, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  });
};
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(text) == false) {
  //Inint cap
  console.log(text.initCap());
  
  
  //Init cap if length >1
  var temp = text.split(" ");
  var t = "";
  temp.map(function(value){
    if(value.length > 1){
      t += value.initCap() + " ";
    }else{
      t += value + " ";
    }
  });
  console.log(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way to capitalize the first alphabet is:

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
console.log(toTitleCase("anna alàs i jové"));
```

**EDIT :**

To include the words starting with German characters you can use:

```
function toTitleCase1(str)
   {
        return str.replace(/[\w\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\xff]+/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
   }
console.log(toTitleCase1("ànna alàs i jové"));
```

Comment: when the first alphabet is special character it fails e.g. ànna alàs i jové. It returns àNna Alàs I Jové which is wrong N should not be capital

Comment: Oh I missed that case now I have edited the code you can check it out

Answer (score -1):

this will solve Your problem.
http://plnkr.co/edit/7ggKNRw7nwCLmPN0y4Az?p=preview

```
      return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b(\w)/g, s => s.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Not working this is the result from this "àNna AlàS I Jové "